# Serving Magento Catalog From SOLR

Tags: magento, solr

So far, magento with SOLR has been a great combination. But SOLR is currently being used as a search index.
I intend to serve the Entire Catalog with Magento from SORL with all features like, layered navigation, sorting, pagination etc. I have heard and seen few implementations, but I don't have a fair idea how to start and what are the do(s) and don't(s)

Any body can point me in right direction ? Once Done, I'll share complete method here. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Magento EE 1.13.0.x has this feature, you would want to enable it here, System->Configuration->Catalog->Catalog Search

And then Set Enable Solr Engine for Catalog Navigation to yes  or this might also help to integrate custom functionality http://www.summasolutions.net/blogposts/magento-apache-solr-integration-part-iii-indexing-custom-data